# How to return struct from CGO

Tags: struct, shared-libraries, cgo

I'd like to call a Go function from C which returns a struct and within C I'd like to work on the struct.

The goal is to fill the struct with data and return the information. I don't know which format is best to pass. I need to get information in the C code about the length of the returned data, and each `str` and `l` value of the struct.

(The function I call is not `strings.Split())`. It is something more complicated, but the return values I need are both a `char*` and an `int`)

My Go source:

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)


type retvalue struct {
    str *C.char
    l   int
}

// This is what I want to achieve (or something similar):
// func Split(input *C.char) []retvalue {
//    ...
//    ...
//    return ret
// }

//export Split
func Split(input *C.char) {
    all := strings.Split(C.GoString(input), ",")
    ret := []retvalue{}
    for _, str := range all {
        ret = append(ret, retvalue{str: C.CString(str), l: len(str)})
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ret)
    // return ret
}

func main() {}
```

This is my C code:

```
#include "libsplitter.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* input="Hello,nice,world";
    Split(input);
    // do something with the return values from my Split()
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run the code (on macOS) with

```
go build -o libsplitter.dylib -buildmode=c-shared main.go
cc splitit.c -o splitit -lsplitter -L.
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./splitit
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

My C file:

```c
#include "libsplitter.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct splitvalues* sv;
    sv = Split("hello,nice,world",",");

    printf("%d\n",sv->count);
    char** cptr = sv->splitted;
    int *i = sv->lengths;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sv->count; j++)
    {
        printf("%zu %s %d\n",j,*cptr,*i);
        cptr++;
        i++;
    }

    free(sv->splitted);
    free(sv->lengths);
    return 0;
}
```

and my Go file:

```go
package main

/*

struct splitvalues {
    char** splitted;
    int* lengths;
    int count;
};

*/
import "C"

import (
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)

//export Split
func Split(original *C.char, split *C.char) *C.struct_splitvalues {
    inputstring := C.GoString(original)
    splitstring := C.GoString(split)
    goResult := strings.Split(inputstring, splitstring)
    size := len(goResult)

    cLenghtsInt := C.malloc(C.size_t(size) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(C.int(0))))
    cSplittedStrings := C.malloc(C.size_t(size) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))
    returnStruct := (*C.struct_splitvalues)(C.malloc(C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(C.struct_splitvalues{}))))

    ints := (*[1<<30 - 1]C.int)(cLenghtsInt)[:size:size]
    a := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.char)(cSplittedStrings)

    for i, v := range goResult {
        ints[i] = C.int(len(v))
    }

    for idx, substring := range goResult {
        a[idx] = C.CString(substring)
    }

    returnStruct.splitted = (**C.char)(cSplittedStrings)
    returnStruct.lengths = (*C.int)(cLenghtsInt)
    returnStruct.count = C.int(len(goResult))

    return returnStruct
}
func main() {}
```

The output is

```
3
0 hello 5
1 nice 4
2 world 5
```

as expected.

I can't promise that this is the best way and that there are no errors, so don't take this as a reference.